# for loop decrease variable in loop

Tags: java

I want to decrease the variable loop in for loop. What can I do?
When I do `loop--`.It will forever loop happened

```java
for (int loop=0;loop<number.length-1;loop++)
     {
         if (number[loop] != number[loop+1])
         {
             if (loop > 0 && freq_array[loop-1]== 1 )
             {  
                 loop--;  //this line 
                 continue;
             }
             freq=1;
             freq_array[loop]=freq;

         }
         else if (number[loop] == number[loop+1])
         {
             freq++;
             freq_array[loop]=freq;
         }
     }
```

@cameron1024 advice me to use while loop but it has forever loop anyway?

```
while (loop<number.length-1)
     {
         if (number[loop] != number[loop+1])
         {
             if (loop > 0 && freq_array[loop-1]== 1 )
             {  
                 continue;
             }
             else
             {
                freq=1;
                freq_array[loop]=freq;
                loop++;
             }

         }
         else 
         {
             freq++;
             freq_array[loop]=freq;
             loop++;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Why do you want to decrement `loop`? You are causing the current iteration of the loop to repeat itself forever. I'm assuming that's not what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to check the frequency of this ```9 9 8 5 5``` and add to ```freq_array``` Iike this ```2 1 2``` (2 it mean 9 have 2) but it is ```2 1 0 2``` then I ```loop-- ``` because don't want 0 in my array @Eran

Comment: Watch out for `if (number[loop] != number[loop+1])` possibly throwing some `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, if the loop does not run forever due to decrementing and incrementing in one run.

Comment: @JackyTeerapat In this case you would be better off storing a separate index for freq_array that you increase separately from the variable loops. Unfortunately, that would often lead to trailing zeros at the end of your array, but this could be eliminated with a dynamically sized storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Secondly, a `for` loop is just a `while` loop with decoration. For example:

```
for (<initializer>; <termination>; <increment>) {
    <loop body>
}
```

is identical (with minor scope changes) to:

```
<initializer>;
while (<termination>) {
    <loop body>
    <termination>
}
```

The reason it is looping forever is that you have not changed your termination condition to match the fact that the variable is now decreasing. Your termination condition checks that `loop` does not go **above** a certain value. And since `loop` only ever decreases, that condition is always satisfied, and so the loop continues infinitely.

P.S. avoid naming variables `like_this` in java, they are typically done `likeThis`

Answer (score 1):

i think you want this.

```
for (int loop = number.length - 1; loop > 0; loop--)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to count down:
Just do `for(int i=10;i>=0;i--)`
`int i = 10` makes a new int initialised with 10
The next part is your loops exit condition.
as long a i>=10,the loop will run
And lastly i-- decrement the variable i

Your loop is infinite because the loop++ in the making of the loop and your loop-- are falling together creating a

```
int i = 1;
while(i < 10) {
    i++;
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (loop<number.length-1)
     {
         if (number[loop] != number[loop+1])
         {              
            freq=1;
            freq_array[loop]=freq;
            loop++;


         }
         else 
         {
             freq++;
             if (loop > 0 && freq_array[loop-1]== 1 )
             {  
                 freq_array[loop-1]=freq;
             }
             else
             {
                freq_array[loop]=freq;
             }
             loop++;
         }
     }
```

I'm done now thank you every one.